# jQuery does not return checked radio value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

UPDATE:
The problem is more complex. Looks like it involves accordion header not passing .click events correctly, and has nothing to do with :checked selector. All of this example work fine in a test file.

**Please see [Radio input in header of accordion problem ?BUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278756/radio-input-in-header-of-accordion-problem)**

I have a form with several radio elements, each names "rx" (where x is 1..3), .buttonset() applied. 
with

e.g id=3

```
alert ($('input:radio[name=r'+id+']').val());
//returns value of the first radio in the set

alert ($('input:radio[name=r'+id+']:checked').val());
//returns 'undefined', even one of the radios is checked.
```

and I've tried both `:checked')[0]`, `:checked').get(0)`, `:checked').attr('id')`

I wonder why the first method returns a value... Does it have anything to do with .buttonset adding classes/element??

Any advice is appreciated!

PS. $('input:radio[name=r'+id+']').get(0) 
returns [object HTMLInputElement], I guess the way its supposed to. But this object has no .html() or .val() methods. $('input:radio[name=r'+id+']:checked').get(0) is still 'undefined'.

PPS. forcing visibility for ui-helper-hidden-accessible
buttonset does not change "checked" for the original radio elements.
I guess I can use .ui-state-active to check active radio instead... Any better way?

Comment: @ selytch what o/p do you need exactly ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for telling us you have an accordion....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't return a value is because when you use the `:checked` selector if the radio is not selected it won't be part of the resultset. Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" name="r2" value="2" />
```

Now:

```
alert($('input:radio[name=r1]').val()); // alerts 1
alert($('input:radio[name=r1]:checked').val()); // alerts 1
alert($('input:radio[name=r2]').val()); // alerts 2
alert($('input:radio[name=r2]:checked').val()); // alerts undefined as the button is not selected
```

Comment: I understand this is how its supposed to work, can adding .buttonset be screwing up the things?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-

```
$("input[name='radio_name']:checked").val();
```

Comment: the `@` was deprecated in jQuery 1.2 and removedin jQuery 1.3 - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Read the page about selectors, especially this one http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
alert ($(':radio[name^=r]:checked').val());
```

should return the checked button's value, or undefined if none is selected.

Comment: I know this seems like a straightforward problem, but can .buttonset()  be affecting the things or its my typo somewhere in the code???

Comment: hmm... read the selector page I gave you. the proposed selector in this solution will match 'r', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'rWhatever', etc. Just replace the selector for your need. The problem is not JQuery, but how you make use of it. This is typically called RTFM

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a jQuery plugin for setting and getting radio-button values. It also respects the "change" event on them.

```
(function ($) {

    function changeRadioButton(element, value) {
        var name = $(element).attr("name");
        $("[type=radio][name=" + name + "]:checked").removeAttr("checked");
        $("[type=radio][name=" + name + "][value=" + value + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
        $("[type=radio][name=" + name + "]:checked").change();
    }

    function getRadioButton(element) {
        var name = $(element).attr("name");
        return $("[type=radio][name=" + name + "]:checked").attr("value");
    }

    var originalVal = $.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(value) {

        //is it a radio button? treat it differently.
        if($(this).is("[type=radio]")) {

            if (typeof value != 'undefined') {

                //setter
                changeRadioButton(this, value);
                return $(this);

            } else {

                //getter
                return getRadioButton(this);

            }

        } else {

            //it wasn't a radio button - let's call the default val function.
            if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
                return originalVal.call(this, value);
            } else {
                return originalVal.call(this);
            }

        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Put the code anywhere to enable the addin. Then enjoy! It just overrides the default val function without breaking anything.

You can visit this jsFiddle to try it in action, and see how it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/ffMathy/MN856/